# How to Clear the HTML Editor

Tags: jquery, html

I do have wysihtml5Editor, and I want to clear the value of the editor using jQuery. I have written the code as follows:

```
$(function () {
   $("#cleartext").live('click', function () {
    $('#def_text').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor.clear();
    });
});

<textarea  name="def_text"  id="def_text" class="w100" rows="9" cols="50" data-bind="editor: def_text"></textarea>
<button type="reset" class="btn" id="cleartext"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> New Contract</button>
```

I am not getting the desired result – it shows me the error that editor is not defined.
Suggestions please.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? `live` has been deprecated for ages now. use `on` instead.

Comment: m not sure about this but the latest one...

Comment: ok. then you can do this. `$(document).on('click', '#cleartext', function(){$('#def_text').data("wysihtml5").editor.clear();});` to find out the version of jquery : `$.fn.jquery`

Comment: ok.. live is deprecated before 1.7 - so you are better off using `on` Try what I recommended in previous comment

Comment: are you sure that is the code for clearing the editor?

Comment: k so can u give me some other way to write the code

Comment: the scenario is like i have to clear the text of this Editor

Answer (score 3):

I think you're making it too complex.
Just set your variable and link it to your textarea and then use only the variable :

```
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("myTextarea");
editor.clear();
```

or

```
editor.setValue('', true);
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're making this more complicated than necessary. How about you just try:

```
$("#cleartext").click(function () {
    $('#def_text').val('');
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDbVs/).

Comment: It works for me. Could you list the exact steps you're taking?

Comment: yes i have define <textarea> given id="def_text" and a button called as New and given id="cleartext" and made one js file and include that file into this view.and js file consists of the code given by you.

Comment: Could you update your question so that I can see all the code you have so far?

Comment: Ah, I see the edits. What I meant was you should try the *entire* snippet of code above and replacing it with the one I gave.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to clear the data in my single page application:

When I tried

```
('#comments').data("wysihtml5").editor.clear() // Got error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'editor' of undefined**
```

When I tried

```
var editor = $('#comments').wysihtml5();
editor.clear(); // This clears only the textarea which is hidden. Did not clear the Editor.
```

So this is what I did, (Might not be a good approach, but this cleared my textarea)

```
$(".wysihtml5-sandbox").remove();
$("#comments").show();
$('#comments').val('');
```

and  then Initialize the Editor again,

```
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("comments", { // id of textarea element
  toolbar:      "wysihtml5-toolbar", // id of toolbar element
  parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules, // defined in parser rules set
  stylesheets: "/cca/css/richtext.css"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. ,create a div tag, inside put your **textarea** element

```
<div id="CommentTextArea">

<textarea  name="comment_text"  id="comment"  rows="9" cols="50" ></textarea>

</div>

<button type="submit"  id="send"> Send </button>
```

**In your .js file**

```
 $(function(){

// Initialize the Editor
$("#comment").wysihtml5({

toolbar: {
 "size": "xs",    //<buttonsize> // options are xs, sm, lg
"font-styles": false, // Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc.
"emphasis": true, // Italics, bold, etc.
"lists": false, // (Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers.
"html": false, // Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML.
"link": true, // Button to insert a link.
"image": true, // Button to insert an image.
"color": false, // Button to change color of font
"blockquote": false, // Blockquote

}
});

// when the send button is clicked

$('#send').click(function(){

   setTimeout(function(){
        //remove  wysihtml5Editor contents  
   $("#CommentTextArea").html('<textarea  name="comment_text"  id="comment"  rows="9" cols="50" ></textarea>');

// and then Initialize the Editor again,

$("#comment").wysihtml5({

toolbar: {
 "size": "xs",    //<buttonsize> // options are xs, sm, lg
"font-styles": false, // Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc.
"emphasis": true, // Italics, bold, etc.
"lists": false, // (Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers.
"html": false, // Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML.
"link": true, // Button to insert a link.
"image": true, // Button to insert an image.
"color": false, // Button to change color of font
"blockquote": false, // Blockquote
   }});

     }, 1000);   

});



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I write few lines of custom JS code. I think they can help you.

```
var content = $('#textareaId');
var contentPar = content.parent()
contentPar.find('.wysihtml5-toolbar').remove()
contentPar.find('iframe').remove()
contentPar.find('input[name*="wysihtml5"]').remove()
content.show()
$('#textareaId').val('');
$("#textareaId").wysihtml5();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using bootstrap 3 wysiHtml5 editor, and none of the solutions given here  worked for me,
I used this one and it worked

$('#controlid ~ iframe').contents().find('.wysihtml5-editor').html('');

Answer (score -1):

Are you initializing correctly? The docs show something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("def_text");

    $("#cleartext").on('click', function () {
        $('#def_text').data("wysihtml5").editor.clear();
    });
});
```

Or, closer to yours,

```
var wysihtml5Editor = $('#def_text').wysihtml5();
```